# Transformation between two Rotated Coordinate Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, transformation

Following example:
I attached a Camera to a drone and flew over a terrain, for every picture it took I have the exact Orientation of the Camera with Respect to the World.
Now lets say I have a perfect Simulation of that, but my Simulation has a arbitrary Coordinate System which I do not know. The only thing I know is the Position and Orientation of every Image of my Camera with respect to the Simulated-world.

Now with that How can I get the Transformation, so that I could also transform camera orientations in the Future from my World Frame to my Simulation frame, without knowing their position/orientation in the Simulation Frame.

So I have:

Rwc(0) : Rotation from Camera to World for 1 single Image with index 0

Rsc(0) : Rotation from Camera to Simulation for 1 single Image with index 0

No I know I could get the transformation for the first image like this:

Rsw(0) = Rsc(0) * Rwc(0)⁻¹

Rsc(0) = Rsw(0) * Rwc(0)

But how can I get the Tranformation for any arbitrary Orientation in my World Coordinate system??? So that:

Rsc(x) = TRANSFORMATION * Rwc(x)

Comment: I don't think there's a mathematically rigorous way of doing this. I suppose what I'd do is: figure out what the camera image should look like as a function of the shift in position and orientation, compare to what it actually does look like, use some sort of metric for goodness of fit, then use some algorithm like steepest-descents to try to find the orientation and position which optimize the goodness of fit. That's assuming I didn't just eyeball it: our brains are pretty good at saying "oh, this was taken from the front of the building and I rotated the camera a bit clockwise".

Comment: yes exatly! The whole time I am thinking it cannot be that difficult but somehow nothing I tried works. Maybe to give you more information, the "Simulation" in my example is a photogrammetric software, with which I created a mesh of the ground. Now in the next fly I want to simulate camera rays from the drone to the mesh, but i just cannot figure out the transformation between mesh and drone. Even though I have the Pose of the Images in Mesh Frame and Drone Frame of the creation flight

Comment: Hey @David What do you think about this Idea: So for my Image 0 I can surely calculate the transformation from world to simulation. So I transform Cam in World to Sim, than I do raytracing to the mesh and receive a 3D Point of that Mesh, which I could backproject to the World. So now I can Transform my Mesh/Simulation environment to the World frame? Would that work?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know much about meshes or ray-tracing, which weren't mentioned in your original post. You say that you can surely calculate the transformation from the world to the simulation, though. Isn't that what you were asking how to do in your original post?

Comment: my initial idea was to calculate the transformation between the camera poses from wold to simulation(mesh). But know I am wondering if it would be easier to calculate the tranformation of the simulation ( the whole mesh) to the world